# Why did Ted go to MacLaren's to call the locksmith when Barney locks him out in "Now We're Even"?

Tags: how-i-met-your-mother

When Barney locks Ted out of his apartment while Ted in his pajamas, why does he go to MacLaren's to call his locksmith? This doesn't seem to make any sense since:

1. Barney probably has a cell phone
2. IIRC the location of the apartment is never established, so why would he go all the way to MacLaren's? It could be miles away for all we know.

****Note*** that this is the new apartment that Quinn used to live in, not his original one which was of course right above MacLaren's.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was established that MacLaren's is right below the apartment where Ted & Marshall (& Lily) were living.  (I recall them agreeing to meet "downstairs" on several occasions, and then they were sitting int he bar.)

Comment: @Steve-O no. This is his *new* apartment, the one that Quinn lived in before she moved in with Barney.

Comment: And why would Barney give him his cell phone?